# Which plugin used by gmail to show mail time or date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datetime, gmail

I wanted to know that which js plugin used by gmail to show mail time(if today's mail) or date.

If mail received today itself then it shows time '1:18 pm' otherwise date like 'sep 5'. And if mail was received i last year then it showing date like '11/12/13'.

Is there any js plugin or rails to do that ?
Like this [image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why you need any plugin or gem for this. You can easily do it with helper.
In your helper :

```
require 'date'

def time_date(date)
  if date.year > Time.now.year
    date.strftime('%d/%m/%y')
  else 
    date.to_date == Time.now.to_date ? date.strftime('%l:%M %P') : date.strftime('%b %d')
  end
end
```

in your view :

```
<%= time_date(@model.created_at) %>
```

As per your comment You do want to use jquery to show datetime instead of helper. So there is no direct plugin for this. But you can use this https://github.com/agschwender/jquery.formatDateTime to achieve what you want.

Lets consider on your view you have following div:

```
<div class="start">2014/09/11 09:00:03</div>
```

Now use `jquery.formatDateTime` to format div date :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var datetime = new Date($('.start').text());
  var today = new Date();
  if(today.getFullYear() > datetime.getFullYear()){
    $('.start').formatDateTime('mm/dd/y');
  }
  else{
    if(today.getDate() > datetime.getDate()){
      $('.start').formatDateTime('M m');
    }
    else{
      $('.start').formatDateTime('g:ii a');
    }
  }

});
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: I can achieve it by helper method. But what if I have 1000 records then I have to call this helper method 1000 times that will reduce my performance. That's why looking for js plugin.

Comment: There is no direct plugin in jquery to do so. But you can achive it with https://github.com/agschwender/jquery.formatDateTime I have updated my answer acordingly

Answer (score 1):

You can use `moment.js` for this kind of date and time display. Import `moment.js` and call this function, passing the date as an argument.

```
function emailTimeDisplay(dbDate) {
    dbDate = new moment(dbDate);
    var currentDate = new moment();
    if (currentDate.isSame(dbDate, 'day'))
        return dbDate.format('h:mm a');
    else if (currentDate.isSame(dbDate, 'year'))
        return dbDate.format("MMM DD");
    else
        return dbDate.format("MM/DD/YYYY");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use moment.js for this is kind of date and time display
import moment.js and call below function with passing date as argument.

```
function emailTimeDisplay(dbDate) {
    dbDate = new moment(dbDate);
    var currentDate = new moment();
    if (currentDate.isSame(dbDate, 'day'))
        return dbDate.format('h:mm a');
    else if (currentDate.isSame(dbDate, 'year'))
        return dbDate.format("MMM DD");
    else
        return dbDate.format("MM/DD/YYYY");
}
```